# Ran make V=s command to build the toolchain for my Audiocodec Board AC494. Returns error

Tags: makefile, openwrt, toolchain

"make[3]: Entering directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/feeds/packages/utils/attr'
if [ -f /home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/attr.default.install.clean ]; then rm -f /home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/attr.default.install /home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/pkginfo/attr.default.install.clean; fi
CFLAGS="-Os -pipe -mno-branch-likely -mips32 -mtune=mips32 -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -msoft-float  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro  -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include " CXXFLAGS="-Os -pipe -mno-branch-likely -mips32 -mtune=mips32 -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -msoft-float  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro  -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/include -I/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/include " LDFLAGS="-L/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib -L/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib -L/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/usr/lib -L/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/toolchain-mipsel_mips32_gcc-4.8-linaro_uClibc-0.9.33.2/lib -znow -zrelro " make -j1 -C /home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/attr-20160302/. AR="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc-ar" AS="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc -c -Os -pipe -mno-branch-likely -mips32 -mtune=mips32 -fno-caller-saves -fno-plt -fhonour-copts -Wno-error=unused-but-set-variable -Wno-error=unused-result -msoft-float  -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -Wl,-z,now -Wl,-z,relro" LD=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-ld NM="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc-nm" CC="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc" GCC="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc" CXX="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-g++" RANLIB="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-gcc-ranlib" STRIP=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-strip OBJCOPY=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-objcopy OBJDUMP=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-objdump SIZE=mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-size CROSS="mipsel-openwrt-linux-uclibc-" ARCH="mipsel" ;
make[4]: Entering directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/attr-20160302'
CCLD     attr
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `llistxattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` lsetxattr'
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `fgetxattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` lremovexattr'
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `removexattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` listxattr'
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `fremovexattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` lgetxattr'
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `setxattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` flistxattr'
./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to `fsetxattr' ./.libs/libattr.so: undefined reference to` getxattr'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:852: recipe for target 'attr' failed
make[4]: *** [attr] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/attr-20160302'
Makefile:92: recipe for target '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/attr-20160302/.built' failed
make[3]: *** [/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/build_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/attr-20160302/.built] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/feeds/packages/utils/attr'
package/Makefile:105: recipe for target 'package/feeds/packages/attr/compile' failed
make[2]: *** [package/feeds/packages/attr/compile] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede'
package/Makefile:101: recipe for target '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.package_compile' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/staging_dir/target-mipsel_mips32_uClibc-0.9.33.2/stamp/.package_compile] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede'
/home/pulkit/new_sdk/lede/include/toplevel.mk:205: recipe for target 'world' failed
make: *** [world] Error 2"

First it retuned an error for "sys/attr.h".
So i copied the file sys/attr.h in my toolchain directory include/sys. And now it returns this error.